# VM Partitioning

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, partition

If this isn't the right place to ask this please redirect me.

I'm using hyper-v to create virtual machines, I have 1.6TB to use, I have the parent on a partition of 50GB, how should I divide up the rest of the space?

Would it be better to create a partition for each VM or leave the remaining space as one partition and put each VM in that one big partition?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should I divide up the rest of the space?

Not at all?

My servers have a 50gb parent partition, and another partition for Hyper-V (OFTNE on a seprate set of discs - one disc = you are dead anyway IO wise).

Why no splitting? that is what VHD files are for. No sense in making separate partitions - you can not expose partitions to Hyper-V anyway. How you think that would work? Jsut store the vm's opn the partition for vm's and make VHD files in there.

Comment: So the VHD's are partitions in there own right?

Comment: What you mean with partitioning? Every VHD is a file. SInce file systems where invented like 40 years ago, you can have different files on one volume. The VHD file then LOOK to a VK like a complete physical disc. Maybe you should read the documentation front to back? If THAT is unclear, there are likely a logt of other musinderstandings about how Hyper-V works.

Comment: Ya I didn't ask that right, but you cleared it up, thanks.